Help with JSON Deserialization Failed on Token 'null' Error While Parsing Nested JSON
I'm trying to write a unit test that mocks child records related to a parent. I'm attempting to use the fflib_ApexMocksUtils.makeRelationship(), but I'm getting a deserialization failure.
Json Deserialization failed on token 'null' and has left off in the middle of parsing a row. Will go to end of row to begin parsing the next row
Here is the JSON:

[{"attributes":{"type":"SalesOrder__c","url":"/services/data/v62.0/sobjects/SalesOrder__c/a55000000000002AAA"},"Id":"a55000000000002AAA","Account__c":"001000000000001AAA","Additional_Turnaround__c":"0","Additional_Turnaround_Missed_Approvals__c":"0","Additional_Turnaround_Revisions__c":"0","Additional_Turnaround_Services__c":"0","Total_Amount_Paid__c":"300.00","Order_Subtotal__c":"300.00","Invoices__r":{"totalSize":1,"done":true,"records":[{"attributes":{"type":"AcctSeed__Billing__c","url":"/services/data/v62.0/sobjects/AcctSeed__Billing__c/a1S000000000003EAA"},"Id":"a1S000000000003EAA","Sales_Order__c":"a55000000000002AAA","AcctSeed__Customer__c":"001000000000001AAA","AcctSeed__Date__c":"2024-12-28"}]}}]

Here is my test method:
@isTest
static void testInvoiceSetOnSalesOrder() {
    fflib_ApexMocks mocks = new fflib_ApexMocks();

    Id mockAccountId = fflib_IDGenerator.generate(Account.SObjectType);
    Id mockSalesOrderId = fflib_IDGenerator.generate(SalesOrder__c.SObjectType);
    Id mockInvoiceId = fflib_IDGenerator.generate(AcctSeed__Billing__c.SObjectType);

    AcctSeed__Billing__c mockInvoice = new AcctSeed__Billing__c(
        Id = mockInvoiceId,
        AcctSeed__Customer__c = mockAccountId,
        Sales_Order__c = mockSalesOrderId,
        AcctSeed__Date__c = System.today()
    );

    List<SalesOrder__c> parents = new List<SalesOrder__c>{
        new SalesOrder__c(
            Id = mockSalesOrderId,
            Account__c = mockAccountId,
            Additional_Turnaround__c = 0,
            Additional_Turnaround_Missed_Approvals__c = 0,
            Additional_Turnaround_Revisions__c = 0,
            Additional_Turnaround_Services__c = 0,
            Total_Amount_Paid__c = 300.00,
            Order_Subtotal__c = 300.00
        )
    };

    List<List<AcctSeed__Billing__c>> children = new List<List<AcctSeed__Billing__c>>{
        new List<AcctSeed__Billing__c>{
            new AcctSeed__Billing__c(
                Id = mockInvoiceId, 
                Sales_Order__c = mockSalesOrderId, 
                AcctSeed__Customer__c = mockAccountId,
                AcctSeed__Date__c = System.today()
            )
        }
    };

    System.debug('Parents: ' + parents);
    System.debug('Children: ' + children);

    List<SalesOrder__c> mockSalesOrdersWithInvoices = (List<SalesOrder__c>) fflib_ApexMocksUtils.makeRelationship(
        SalesOrder__c.class,
        parents,
        AcctSeed__Billing__c.Sales_Order__c,
        children
    );

    System.debug('Mock SalesOrders with Invoices: ' + mockSalesOrdersWithInvoices);

    ISalesOrdersSelector salesOrderSelector = (ISalesOrdersSelector) mocks.mock(SalesOrdersSelector.class);

    mocks.startStubbing();
        mocks.when(salesOrderSelector.selectByIdWithInvoices(new Set<Id>{mockSalesOrderId}))
            .thenReturn(mockSalesOrdersWithInvoices);
    mocks.stopStubbing();
    
    IAcctSeedBillingsService billingService = (IAcctSeedBillingsService) mocks.mock(IAcctSeedBillingsService.class);
    Application.Service.setMock(IAcctSeedBillingsService.class, billingService);

    List<AcctSeed__Billing__c> invoices = new List<AcctSeed__Billing__c>{ mockInvoice };
    IAcctSeedBillings billingDomain = AcctSeedBillings.newInstance(invoices);

    List<SalesOrder__c> salesOrdersToUpdate = billingDomain.prepareSalesOrdersForUpdate(true);

    System.assertEquals(1, salesOrdersToUpdate.size(), 'Expected one SalesOrder to be updated');
    System.assertEquals(mockInvoiceId, salesOrdersToUpdate[0].Invoice__c, 'Expected SalesOrder.Invoice__c to match the Invoice ID');

    ((ISalesOrdersSelector) mocks.verify(salesOrderSelector, 1)).selectByIdWithInvoices(new Set<Id>{mockSalesOrderId});
    ((IAcctSeedBillingsService)mocks.verify(billingService, 0)).updateSalesOrders(salesOrdersToUpdate);
}

I'm pretty new to using the fflib testing framework. Can anyone help point out where I may be going wrong?

Have you looked at the fflib Github to see what the methods are doing with the JSON?

There are some folks who downvote not allow me answer but still making an attempt to help you out:
I did your code review I feel the following are the issues with your code-:

You have not set up a test data factory in your code where test data needs to be created. Since your code does not include any DML statement.

You are not setting up a mock layer for responses in your test class. Without this, the test class will not recognize or process the JSON response correctly. And hence deserialisation won't occur.

I would suggest go through the salesforce developer guide on how to write test class for callouts. Understand the concept and then try this.


